# MySQL-client and MySQL-server are obsoleted by... themselves

Tags: mysql, centos

When I run `yum check` on my Centos system, I get the following error:

```
MySQL-client-5.5.14-1.linux2.6.i386 is obsoleted by MySQL-client-5.5.14-1.linux2.6.i386
MySQL-server-5.5.14-1.linux2.6.i386 is obsoleted by MySQL-server-5.5.14-1.linux2.6.i386
```

And I really can't understand what it means, I tried to search for `MySQL-client obsoleted` on Google but I didn't find anything.

Of course, running `yum update MySQL-client MySQL-server` has no effect at all as it says `No Packages marked for Update`.

Comment: Are you using DirectAdmin? `cat /etc/yum.conf`? `rpm -qa | grep MySQL`?

Comment: @quanta, Yes, I do. I think you found the problem, I've the following line in `/etc/yum.conf`:`exclude=apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot*`. However, `rpm -qa` shows that MySQL client, server, shared and devel are installed with version 5.5.14-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've the following line in `/etc/yum.conf`: `exclude=apache* httpd* mod_*
>   mysql* MySQL* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot*`

DirectAdmin configures yum to exclude `mysql*`, `MySQL`* updates to protect it's own packages.

> However, `rpm -qa` shows that MySQL client, server, shared and devel
>   are installed with version 5.5.14-1.

They are installed via rpm, not yum.